# Mixing HTML5 and Flash using AIR for IOS, Android, Windows and OSX?

Tags: air

AIR newbie question.  I currently have a single page app written in flex.  I'm writing all my new code in HTML5.  I would like to be able to integrate these into a single app.  This is obviously not a problem on desktop browsers.  The key targets are iOS and Android tablets.  A desktop app is a secondary priority, but a benefit.  Looking at Adobe's docs, it's clear I can take my Flex app and deliver it on iOS and Android.  However, as I create HTML5 content, I need to deliver the old and new content together in a single app on iOS and Android.  Can I deliver a hybrid HTML5/flash code as an installable app using AIR?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: what programming software do you use ? did you ever compiled an air app ?

Comment: We have an AIR app based on Flex using FlashBuilder. It is a fullscreen app.  I am writing new code in html5.  We are breaking the Flex app into a few pieces that end up as smaller embedded swf's on html pages.  They are controlled by calls from javascript.

Comment: so basically you want the final html5 page, that contains the old swf parts, to be an AIR app so you can run it on IOS and Android ?

Comment: Think if it this way.  I currently have a full page Flex app.  I will also have a full page html5 app.  I will also have a 'launcher' page.  I want a single app that launches the launcher page, which will then allow the user to go to/from each of the other pages.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, unfortunately i still didn't get the point.

but i think you're gonna have to put the old content into a very new application.

i dont have experience in FlashBuilder, but i recoment you to use Adobe Flash Pro CS6 for full IOS and Android compatibility.

download the 30 day trial from the adobe website.

in the CS6 version the extensions you'll need ( AIR for Android & AIR for IOS ) are already in there.

for older versions you'd have to google them.

if you start Adobe Flash Pro CS6 you can choose one of these options :

AIR ( 2.0 ) : for desktop ( PC and OSX )
AIR for Android : self explained
AIR for IOS : you got the point ^^

so you can choose one of these and start designing the main app.

if you want to put the old SWF in it , you can do so.

for the html5 content you've done , you could use `HTMLLoader`.

after finishing the first project, cou can simply copy the code and content to a new project  or you can output the project for all the 3 diferent OS types. you may want to chance some proppertys like width and height , frame mode, premissions and stuff like that.

hope you got the main idea.

there are tons of tutorials out there if you have problems to embett the old content.

g.r. Ace

Comment: I think you are right.  I'll need to create an AIR app that runs the Flex code and embeds the HTML5 portion in StageWebView (Docs say HTMLLoader does not work on mobile).  I'll give that a go.